# LINQ to Objects Optimization Techniques?

Tags: performance, optimization, linq-to-objects

What LINQ to Objects optimization techniques do you use or have you seen in the wild?

While waiting for "yield foreach" and other language/compiler optimizations to arrive in C# in 201x, I'm interesting in doing everything possible to make using LINQ everywhere less of a performance pain.

One pattern I've seen so far is creating custom IEnumerable implementations for specific combinators such that the enumerable is not being re-enumerated several times.

Comment: "creating custom IEnumerable implementations for specific combinators such that the enumerable is not being re-enumerated several times" --> tactical use of `ToArray`, surely?

Comment: ToArray is not always the answer. In a recursive scenario for example.

Answer (score 10):

One that I've spotted a few times - don't use:

```
if (query.Count() > 0)
```

... use this instead:

```
if (query.Any())
```

That way it only needs to find the first match.

EDIT: You may also be interested in a [blog post I recently wrote](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/02/10/optimisations-in-linq-to-objects.aspx) about optimisations which *could* be in LINQ to Objects but aren't (or weren't in .NET 3.5).

Additionally, if you're going to do a lot of `x.Contains(y)` operations and `x` is the result of an existing query (i.e. it's not already going to be some optimised collection), you should probably consider building a `HashSet<T>` from `x` to avoid a linear scan (performing the query to produce `x`'s results)  on each iteration.

Comment: Certainly Any is much better than Count. I just disassembled BCL 4 and  ElementAt is now optimized for ILists; it does a simple list[index] lookup in that case.

Comment: I just checked out the BCL 4 Reverse() and it's also slow. It's very trivial to implement a random access reverse enumerable as you mention. I just did so and it's significantly faster. So I'll include this in my bag of tricks.

Comment: You might want to check out the optimizations and tricks I've applied in Extensia: extensia.codeplex.com; it makes use of LINQ to Objects everywhere and includes a hybrid sequence/list type for buffered access to enumerables.